# HTTP spreadsheet web service like Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: libreoffice

Please is there a spreadsheet service for Ubuntu which I can easily install to provide a similar web service just for myself like Google Sheets or Excel online? It can be a really simple spreadsheet solution (sophistication of basic spreadsheet functionality from 20 years ago would be fine, though with the web service access - no complex formula or other modern features that Google Sheets and Excel offer are needed).

I often find a spreadsheet better than a document for organising text (as cells, columns and rows etc), please say if you know of something else that might be suitable.

I saw LibreOffice but it seemed that's a complex install to provide the web service over HTTP.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think such a solution will be simpler than just installing LibreOffice or another alternative: https://alternativeto.net/software/libreoffice/?platform=linux

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Excellent thank you, this included some options I hadn't seen, and I'll revisit LibreOffice Online.

Answer (score 0):

What about https://ethercalc.net/ ? You can try it out without having to install anything.

[image: Ethercalc screenshot]

If you like it and you want to own the web server, then just follow the local install instructions on https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc

If the goal is to have 'real Excel sheets', and have it synchronized in several devices, then I would suggest that you create an Owncloud or Nextcloud server with one of these plugins:

- https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/richdocuments
- https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/onlyoffice
- https://nextcloud.com/blog/how-to-install-collabora-online-in-nextcloud-hub/
- https://owncloud.com/collabora/

Though probably Libreoffice is easier.

Comment: Ethercalc seems like a great possibility, I will investigate further. My development skills are basic so please correct me, but looking at GitHub I wasn't sure if/how actively this is maintained? I'm slightly concerned it might not up to date with security and vulnerabilities (noob asking here)? 
Please do you happen to know if there'd be any good methods to improve security (e.g. using a Yubikey or any other add ons that can make a good difference)?

Comment: I'm going to reread the Nextcloud/collabora. First time I looked at it I thought minimum purchase was $3.6K/year as I only saw enterprise options, but now I think there may be a personal use option, which would be great.

Owncloud is new to me so thanks for sharing.

Comment: I also found https://sandstorm.io/ for installing Ethercalc. It's new to me but that sounds like a great easy option, are there any disadvantages of using that type of install?

Comment: Ethercalc repo was last updated Dec 2020, it's not too bad, but it's not being actively developed (no new features, etc.). Not sure about the security improvement methods, but Sandstorm looks an easy solution. You could also build your own Nextcloud server without paying, but might be a harder process. Please vote up the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive and very helpful answers. I've clicked the upvote and it says 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' Thanks for sharing your knowledge & expertise.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hard task to get a really simple spreadsheet solution. Many software packages available will allow you to set up a simple database with just a few clicks. And then numerous Web sites offer the same thing, but they're all free. If you want something more advanced than what you'd find in a spreadsheet program like Microsoft Excel, try using Google Docs or https://www.coupler.io/bigquery-integrations/asana-to-bigquery. These programs allow you to create your databases and tables on the Web, which are always accessible from any computer or mobile device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).